# how to input current date in text box value with show my additional data

Tags: javascript, php

how to input current date in text box value with show my additional data in the text field.
 my code is.

html input box

```
 <input type="text" id="lro" class="form-control" name="lrno" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["con_branch_name"]; ?>LR151210<?php echo $_SESSION["con_branch_code"]; ?>">
```

my script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('lro').value = Date();
</script>
```

**how to i show either the two data in text box value**

Comment: document.getElementById("lro").value = document.getElementById("lro").value + Date();

Comment: `document.getElementById('lro').value += ' ' + Date();` is somewhat less to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = Date();
    var ele = document.getElementById('lro');
    ele.value = ele.value + date;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = document.getElementById("lro").value;
document.getElementById('lro').value = x + Date();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery:

```
var current_date= Date();
$('#lro').val($('#lro').val() + current_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.onload = function(){
        var date = Date();
        var valElem = document.getElementById('lro');         
        valElem.value = valElem.value + date;
    }
</script>
```